# error installing packages in R. (Windows)

Tags: r, rlang

I just installed R and Rstudio and I'm new to programming in general.

I just tried to install "ggally" library for data visualization but it's showing me the following repetetive error.
Am I doing something wrong?

```
ERROR: dependencies 'dplyr', 'ellipsis', 'glue', 'lifecycle', 'magrittr', 'purrr', 'rlang', 'tibble', 'tidyselect', 'vctrs' are not available for package 'tidyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/smain/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/tidyr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'ggplot2', 'dplyr', 'forcats', 'lifecycle', 'plyr', 'progress', 'reshape', 'rlang', 'scales', 'tidyr' are not available for package 'GGally'
* removing 'C:/Users/smain/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/GGally'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘GGally’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\smain\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpI92I7C\downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Hard to understand where/when this error occured, did you in the `console` tab type `install.packages("ggally")`?
Then to use it, `library("ggally")`?

Comment: it happened just now i used "install.packages("GGally", repos = "https://cran.r-project.org", type= "source")" command

Comment: Do you get any option of installing the dependencies (e.g tidyr)? Check here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/GGally/versions/1.5.0

Comment: no i didn't get any option and also ggally is the first package i tried to install. is that the reason?

Comment: Not really sure, perhaps try `install.packages("tidyr")` first and see if you get the dependencies needed then

Comment: Run `isntall.packages("tidyverse")` than try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be conservative about it and do two steps first:

1- If you have an active Antivirus on your computer, temporarily disable it.

2- If you use **RStudio**, close the software, right-click on the icon and choose `Run as administrator` to open it.

Then, you can re-install the package with the right `repository` address as below:

```
install.packages('GGally', dependencies=TRUE, repos="https://CRAN.R-project.org/")
library(GGally)
```

I hope it helps.